# Is it discouraged for a Node module to use native OS binaries?

Tags: node.js

I noticed that a lot of Node modules for doing standard Unix operations ([rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf), [mkdirp](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp), [tar](https://github.com/npm/node-tar), etc) seem to be written entirely in pure JavaScript.

I would've thought it would be better for performance to spawn the OS's installed binaries (like `rm`, `mkdir`, `tar`) for these tasks where possible, and only fall back to a pure-Node solution when those binaries aren't available (e.g. Windows). But most modules seem to prefer to do everything in Node.

Why don't these apps use native commands where available? Is it discouraged, and why?

Comment: the only good reason i can think of is that spinning up a process can be expensive compared to performing the operation internally

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/felixge/faster-than-c. In some cases you can write javascript that is as fast as or a bit faster than C. The upshot is garbage collection, callbacks and all the js goodness you want in your code. The question is not `why not native` the question is `which is faster` and it depends on a case by case basis. The only way to know for sure is to benchmark (and benchmark correctly) then choose the right solution.

Comment: Even if JS goodness makes it easy to write very fast code (almost approaching the speed of some C code), I doubt anyone could write JS equivalents that come anywhere near the performance of extremely mature Unix commands like `tar`. Extracting a large tarball must be miles faster using the native `tar`, even allowing for process spin-up time. If Node's tar module could beat Unix's native tar, then Unix would switch to that.

Comment: according to someone's benchmark, node-tar is ~1450 times slower at extracting tarballs than native tar. even if they manage to improve on this, it's hard to imagine it ever getting anywhere near the speed of native tar. https://github.com/npm/node-tar/issues/23

Comment: FWIW if you're looking for a faster tar implementation, look at [tar-fs](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs/blob/master/README.md#performance).

Comment: Also don't forget that spawning child processes incurs overhead, so you don't want to be doing it very rapidly.